# getElementById(element).innerHTML cache?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

This is my page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Marketing Tracking</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" id="form" method="post">
            <div id="namevalues">
                <span id="span:1">
                    <input type="text" id="name:1" onchange="changed(this)" style="width:300px;"/>
                    <input id="value:1" type="number" min="0" value="0" /><br /></span>
            </div>
            <input type="button" id="add" value="Add 1" />
            <br />
            <textarea name="talk" style="width:500px;height:175px;"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="update" value="Update"/>
        </form>
        <script>
function get(a){return document.getElementById(a);}
    up=get("update");
    up.onclick = function(){
    get("form").submit();
}
get("name:1").onchange = function(){changed(this)};
get("add").onclick = function(){add()};<% z=2 %>
function changed(ele){
    id=ele.id;
    val=ele.value;
    id=id.split(":")[1];
    get("value:"+id).name=get("name:"+id).value;
}
function add(){
    document.getElementById("namevalues").innerHTML+='<span id="span:'+z+'"><input type="text" id="name:'+z+'" onchange="changed(this)" style="width:300px;"/><input id="value:'+z+'" type="number" min="0" value="0" /><br /></span>';
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am very confused as to why when I press the <kbd>Add 1</kbd> button enter some text and then press the <kbd>Add 1</kbd> button again the text that I just entered disappears!

If anyone could give some insight to this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your other values disappear is because when you do `something.innerHTML += something` it will rewrite the HTML for that zone (meaning what was there before is gone and will be replaced with fresh new HTML). What you probably want to do is something along this :

```
function add(){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<span id="span [... the rest of the code ...]<br /></span>';
    document.getElementById("namevalues").appendChild(div);
}
```

Using `appendChild` won't alter the other element that are already in the div `namevalues`.

Comment: I modified it a bit so the createElement is creating the `<span>` tag and just setting the id but worked perfectly. :] `<div>` tags mess with the padding and margins where as `<span>` tags are more just grouping the tags together.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small thing but try using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

When I was using inner.document stuff I had all kinds of problems until I added that code.