# how to change td color, by click on the td(like battleship game)?

Tags: javascript

how to change td color, by click on the td(like battleship game)? 
here is the code'with specific id :

```
str +="<td id='" + counter + "' onclick='checkClick(" + counter + "," + i + "," + j + ")' style = 'background-color: Black; height:30px; width:30px'>";
```

(the str in the end will be use with innerHTML that will update this on div inside the body

the checkClick function need to change it , i tried with innerHTML or to get the td by ElementID and it didnt work

Comment: Definitely have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html. A comprehensive guide about event handling in JS.

Comment: My suggestion would be not to += the innerHTML I would append() as I found out in [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068421/getelementbyidelement-innerhtml-cache)

Answer (score 3):

```
# my_markup.html
<td id="clickable">Blah</td>

# my_scripts.js
document.getElementById("clickable").addEventListener("click", tableClicked);
function tableClicked(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
}
```

Comment: the problem is that in the function all the times there is a diffrent id, and setting the game is in the JS

Comment: I used an `id` as an example, but I would actually use a `class` on each item that is clickable (or whatever name is), and then find them by class name and apply the event listener to each. I generally use jQuery, so it would be something like `$('.clickable').click(function(){ $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0000'); });`

Comment: i tried to send the td as an object ...str += "<td id='" + counter + "' onclick='checkClick("+ this.id + ")' style = 'background-color: Black; height:30px; width:30px'>"; but it didnt work .. any idea??

Comment: If you must do it with an inline `onclick` then `this.id` shouldn't be a variable, it's simply a string like so: `str += "<td id='" + counter + "' onclick='checkClick(this.id)' style = 'background-color: Black; height:30px; width:30px'>"`

Comment: Finnaly its works with: onclick='checkClick(this)' ---->by using this i can use the object in my function: function checkClick(td) {

            tfdOBJ = document.getElementById(td.id);
            tfdOBJ.style.background = "White";

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

[Changing Background and Text Color of HTML Elements](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/changehtmlelementcolor.htm)

or this, even simplier approach:

[Change the Background Color of an HTML Element (DIV)](http://www.opensourcevarsity.com/javascriptbasics/l2bchangebgcolorofanhtmlelement)

```
<div id="main" class="main">
  <p>hello!</p>
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function changecolor()
  {
    var mainContent = "";
    mainContent = document.getElementById("main");
    mainContent.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF99";
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: the problem that i have 400 td that i already set in the JS before,with:str += "<td id='" + counter + "' onclick='checkClick(" + counter + "," + i + "," + j + ")' style = 'background-color: Black; height:30px; width:30px'>"; inside the new function that recixing the counter , i cant get the td that i create before...

Comment: i tried to send the td as an object ...str += "<td id='" + counter + "' onclick='checkClick("+ this.id + ")' style = 'background-color: Black; height:30px; width:30px'>";   but it didnt work .. any idea??